# Not receiving crashes on crashlytics anymore on iOS

Tags: ios, crashlytics, twitter-fabric

I have 3 iOS applications on crashlytics, and a few days ago 1 application stopped sending crashes. In Xcode console I see 3 logs:

```
[Crashlytics] Version 3.4.0 (92)
[Crashlytics:Crash] Reporting is disabled
[Crashlytics] Crash reporting could not be initialized
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

This problem freaked me out also!! Just when I was about to release a new version of my app to the app store!

Here was my problem: I had delete some old versions of my app that had never been used for production. This screen in Fabric:

[image]

More specifically, I had deleted version 1.0(1) as it was never put into production and was only there from my debug runs while building the app.

Anyway, make sure your app is not building and running with a version you have deleted. Fabric will not initialize Crashlytics if this:

[image]

matches a deleted version. Hope this saves someone else a freakout!! Agh!

Comment: Hi Jon, with your domain knowledge you for sure should be able to flag duplicates. Please add your answer **once** on the best question and **flag** other as **duplicates** if the are, if not leave a comment on the question pointing to the related one.